# copying a zendframework project in to it's subfolder

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi 
I have a zendframework project. Now it is running in my domain (http://www.mydomain.com).
I want to modify some portion of the site. So I decided to copy all the files and folders to its sub folder (http://www.mydomain.com/zendwork). Is it possible?

I heard that there is a problem in the relative path? Thus so how I change the entire path in an easiest way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.its possible but u need to set the path in .htacess file.

Answer (score 4):

Only the files under the "public" directory need be under your document root. The rest of the codebase ("application", "library", etc) can exist anywhere.

The `APPLICATION_PATH` constant and include path defined in the `public/index.php` file dictate where to find the rest of the application.

The other consideration is to make use of the `BaseUrl` view helper when linking to JavaScript, CSS, image and other "static" assets in your views, eg

```
// view.phtml
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('/images/foo.jpg') ?>" alt="foo">
```

To move your application then only involves moving the "public" contents and editing `index.php`.